# spark-shell throws error in Apache spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have installed hadoop on ubuntu on virtual box(host os Windows 7).I have also installed Apache spark, configured `SPARK_HOME` in `.bashrc` and added `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to `spark-env.sh`. Now when I start the `spark-shell` it throws error and do not initialize spark context, sql context. Am I missing something in installation and also I would want to run it on a cluster (hadoop 3 node cluster is set up).

Comment: Any examples of what you've tried and what errors you're seeing would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: add detailed error you get, and how are you invoking `spark-shell`? did you source the `.bashrc` file after adding new env variables?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am now able to install and run spark without any errors. There was a compatibility issue I suppose between spark 1.6.2 and hadoop 2.6. Now I would like to ask should I be making any master slave setting in the hadoop configuration files too? It would be really helpful if you could provide me some  links

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when trying to install Spark local with Windows 7. Please make sure the below paths is correct and I am sure I will work with you. I answer same question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831841/2516356) So, you can follow the below and it will work.

- Create JAVA_HOME variable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
- Add the following part to your path: ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
- Create SPARK_HOME variable: C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
- Add the following part to your path: ;%SPARK_HOME%\bin
- The most important part Hadoop path should include bin file before winutils.ee as the following: C:\Hadoop\bin Sure you will locate winutils.exe inside this path.
- Create HADOOP_HOME Variable: C:\Hadoop
- Add the following part to your path: ;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin

Now you can run the cmd and write spark-shell it will work.