# The system cannot find the path specified error while running pyspark

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I just downloaded spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz. After downloading I followed the steps mentioned here [pyspark installation for windows 10](http://deelesh.github.io/pyspark-windows.html).I used the comment bin\pyspark to run the spark & got error message

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

Attached is the screen shot of error message[image]

Attached is the screen shot of my spark bin folder
[image]

Screen shot of my path variable looks like

[image]
[image]
I have python 3.6 & Java "1.8.0_151" in my windows 10 system
Can you suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831841/2516356

Comment: I had a similar issue that turned out to be as a result of a JDK upgrade, after the upgrade my JAVA_HOME pointed to the wrong place. Since I had forgotten about the upgrade I had this issue. I used the excellent Procmon from sysinternals to debug the issue as to the eye everything looked good when it wasn't.

Answer (score 27):

Actually, the problem was with the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable path. The `JAVA_HOME` path was set to `.../jdk/bin previously`,

I stripped the last `/bin` part for `JAVA_HOME`  while keeping it (`/jdk/bin`) in system or environment path variable (`%path%`) did the trick.

Comment: This is also the cause of the same problem for me. It's strange that the java path has been set with java/bin predefined.

Comment: My problem was that I had the wrong version name in my JAVA_HOME. Changed it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281" and it works.

Comment: Amazing it worked.

Answer (score 17):

My problem was that the JAVA_HOME was pointing to JRE folder instead of JDK. Make sure that you take care of that

Comment: Actually for me it was exactly opposite and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Worked hours and hours on this. My problem was with Java 10 installation. I uninstalled it and installed Java 8, and now Pyspark works.

Answer (score 2):

For those who use Windows and still trying, what solved to me was reinstalling Python (3.9) **as a local user** (`c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`) and defined both env variables `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to `c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python.exe`

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you found out you had to set these variables up?

Comment: @JorgeEstebanMendoza Sorry for the late response. It was just random googling.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing problems installing Pyspark  (Windows)

**Incorrect JAVA_HOME path**

```
> pyspark  
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Open System Environment variables:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Set JAVA_HOME: System Variables > New:

```
Variable Name: JAVA_HOME
Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261
```

Also, check that SPARK_HOME and HADOOP_HOME are correctly set, e.g.:

```
SPARK_HOME=C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2
HADOOP_HOME=C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2
```

Important: Double-check the following

1. The path exists
2. The path does not contain the `bin` folder

**Incorrect Java version**

```
> pyspark
WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed 
UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
```

Ensure that JAVA_HOME is set to Java 8 (jdk1.8.0)

**winutils not installed**

```
> pyspark
WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate Hadoop executable
```

Download [winutils.exe](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/raw/master/hadoop-3.0.0/bin/winutils.exe) and copy it to your spark home bin folder

```
 curl -OutFile C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\bin\winutils.exe -Uri https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/raw/master/hadoop-3.0.0/bin/winutils.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Switching SPARK_HOME to `C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7` and changing PATH to include `%SPARK_HOME%\bin` did the trick for me.

Originally my SPARK_HOME was set to `C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin` and PATH was referencing it as `%SPARK_HOME%`.

Running a spark command directly in my SPARK_HOME dir worked but only once. After that initial success I then noticed your same error and that `echo %SPARK_HOME%` was showing `C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..` I thought perhaps spark-shell2.cmd had edited it in attempts to get itself working, which led me here.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to define the Windows environment variables such that the Spark bin directory is in your PATH environment variable.

Define the following environment variables using the usual methods for Windows.

First define an environment variable called SPARK_HOME to be C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Then either add %SPARK_HOME%\bin to your existing PATH environment variable, or if none exists (unlikely) define PATH to be %SPARK_HOME%\bin

If there is no typo specifying the PATH, 
echo %PATH% should give you the fully resolved path to the Spark bin directory i.e. it should look like

```
C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;
```

If PATH is correct,  you should be able to type pyspark in any directory and it should run.

If this does not resolve the issue perhaps the issue is as specified in [pyspark: The system cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849585/pyspark-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified?noredirect=1&lq=1) in which case this question is a duplicate.

Comment: No, I did that also restarted my command prompt after setting path variable & then use pyspark comment. I have added my path variable screen shot in first post

Answer (score 0):

Update: in my case it came down to wrong path for JAVA, I got it to work...

I'm having the same problem.  I initially installed Spark through pip, and pyspark ran successfully.  Then I started messing with Anaconda updates and it never worked again.  Any help will be appreciated...

I'm assuming PATH is installed correctly for the original author.  A way to check that is to run `spark-class` from command prompt.  With correct PATH it will return `Usage: spark-class <class> [<args>]` when ran from an arbitrary location.  The error from `pyspark` comes from a string of .cmd files that I traced to the last lines in spark-class2.cmd

This maybe silly, but altering the last block of code shown below changes the error message you get from `pyspark` from "The system cannot find the path specified" to "The syntax of the command is incorrect". Removing this whole block makes `pyspark` do nothing.

```
rem The launcher library prints the command to be executed in a single line suitable for being
rem executed by the batch interpreter. So read all the output of the launcher into a variable.
set LAUNCHER_OUTPUT=%temp%\spark-class-launcher-output-%RANDOM%.txt
"%RUNNER%" -Xmx128m -cp "%LAUNCH_CLASSPATH%" org.apache.spark.launcher.Main 
%* > %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%) do (
  set SPARK_CMD=%%i
)
del %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%
%SPARK_CMD%
```

I removed "del %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%" and saw that the text file generated remains empty.  Turns out "%RUNNER%" failed to find correct directory with java.exe because I messed up the PATH to Java (not Spark).

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set spark-class?I'm getting error message as `'spark-class' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Yes now I'm getting Usage: `spark-class <class> [<args>]` by submitting the command `spark-class`.But still getting `The system cannot find the path specified.` after submitting `pyspark` command

Comment: Try to remove 'del %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%' from bin\spark-class2.cmd and look for the temp file in C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp

It should be called 'spark-class-launcher-output-####.txt' and say something like 'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && python'

What folder did you install your JDK into?

Comment: I'm seeing my `spark-class-launcher-output-20430` in `C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp` is empty.It's showing 0 KB file size.JDK is installed under `C:\Program Files`. Removed `del %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT% from bin\spark-class2`.cmd.Kindly suggest what to do.

Comment: Some component of the installation doesn't like a space in the file path (Program Files).  Try reinstalling Java into C:\Java or something like this

Answer (score 0):

if you use anaconda for window. The below command can save your time

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```

After that restart anaconda and start "jupyter notebook"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I am adding my finding in case it helps anyone.

The issue is mainly due to the line `source "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/load-spark-env.sh` in pyspark file. As you can see it's not expecting 'bin' in SPARK_HOME. All I had to do was remove 'bin' from my SPARK_HOME environment variable and it worked (`C:\spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin` to  `C:\spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\`).

The error on Windows Command Prompt made it appear like it wasn't recognizing 'pyspark', while the real issue was with it not able to find the file 'load-spark-env.sh.'