# Pyspark The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark. I installed Pyspark on my windows machine

I downloaded apache spark from [Spark download url](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

I set HADOOP_HOME and SPARK_HOME in environment variables

[path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5vd9.jpg)

my SPARK_HOME=C:\spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7

my HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7

But when I enter pyspark on command prompt I am getting

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Even if I am going to bin directory and executing pyspark it is throwing same exception

Not sure what I missed here.please help me here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The system cannot find the path specified error while running pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340941/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error-while-running-pyspark)

Answer (score 2):

### Set the path as given below:

### Java

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73

PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin

### Hadoop

Create a folder Hadoop/bin and place the winutils.exe file inside the bin folder.

HADOOP_HOME = C:\Hadoop

PATH = C:\Hadoop\bin

### Spark

Download whichever spark version(eg: spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7)

SPARK_HOME = C:\software\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7

PATH = C:\software\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install spark is by using the python library `findspark`

```py
pip install findspark

import findspark

findspark.init('\path\to\extracted\binaries\folder')

import pyspark
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, did multiple research  and  finally i found that i am having jdk with jdk1.8.0_261  and JRE jre1.8.0_271

As solution, i uninstalled both jdk and jre and then installed jdk1.8.0_261, which basically installed both with same version
jdk1.8.0_261
jre1.8.0_261

which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate the pyspark path and then export that path, then install findSpark package , it will do the rest of the work , for example let's say that my pyspark path is : "/usr/spark-2.4.4/python/pyspark/" so what I have to do is:

```
!export SPARK_HOME="/usr/spark-2.4.4/python/pyspark/"
!pip install findspark

import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with adding this code segment.

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "Your_Hadoop_Home_Path"
# os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "~file_path~\Hadoop\hadoop-3.x.x"
```

#what actually done here is changing the HADOOP_HOME environment path

Comment: Seems like an environment issue and not a code issue. Adding paths to `os.environ` won't fix the issue

Comment: yep, what this do is changing the environment,
which is changing HADOOP_HOME environment